# Identifying Feature Importance in Text

Tags: svm, scikit-learn, importance

I am trying to perform feature interpretability on a text corpus but I am becoming quite confused as to how I identify the importance of particular features (words). I have done substantial research to try and figure this out and have provided an implementation below but for some reason it is not coming out the way I would expect. I'd appreciate direction as to whether I have the wrong theory or if I have a bug in my code.

**Theory:** From what I understand obtaining feature interpretability is easiest when using a linear model. To that end I have trained an SVM with a linear kernel, and a one vs. rest approach for multiclass learning. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592661/determining-the-most-contributing-features-for-svm-classifier-in-sklearn) post I should be able to obtain the individual feature significance from the *coef_* variable of the trained SVM. When parsing my text through either a TF-IDF or Count Vectorizer and I receive the same output (so I am mostly certain this is not related to the issue).

My text corpus is simple, and involves several of the same lines with changes only to a single word. The same is true of the evaluation corpus. As such a classification can only be made using the words: 'cat', 'dog', and 'rat'.

**Code:**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn import svm, metrics

import numpy as np

# Setup training/eval data

Xtrain = [
    "I am a cat",
    "What do i cat",
    "a cat is where its at",
    "how about that cat",
    "the cat there sat",

    "I am a dog",
    "What do i dog",
    "a dog is where its at",
    "how about that dog",
    "the dog there sat",

    "I am a rat",
    "What do i rat",
    "a rat is where its at",
    "how about that rat",
    "the rat there sat",]

Ytrain = [0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2]

Xeval = [
    "it was a cat",
    "it was a dog",
    "it was a rat",

    "I watched cat where it sat",
    "I watched dog where it sat",
    "I watched rat where it sat",]

Yeval = [0,1,2,0,1,2]


# define model

vect = CountVectorizer()
clf = svm.SVC(max_iter=100, tol=1e-4, probability=True, 
kernel='linear', decision_function_shape='ovr' )

Xtrain_vect = vect.fit_transform(Xtrain)
clf.fit(Xtrain_vect, Ytrain)

# fit model
pred = clf.predict(vect.transform(Xeval))
print(metrics.accuracy_score(pred, Yeval))   # Achieves 100% accuracy

#--------------------------
# understanding features
#--------------------------
fn = np.array(vect.get_feature_names())
print(fn)   # prints vocabulary

coef = clf.coef_.toarray()
print(coef.shape) # (3, 16)


# for each of the available classes I try to output the 
# most significant features to that model, because I use 
# a one vs. rest approach I anticipate that I should see
# 'cat', 'dog', and 'rat' as the most significant word
# in each of the three models.

for label in range(coef.shape[0]):

    print('')
    print("Label: ", label)

    cf = coef[label].reshape(-1)

    # sort features in descending order
    order = cf.argsort()
    cf = cf[order][::-1]
    fn = fn[order][::-1]

    # print feature importance 
    for f, c in zip(fn, cf):
        print(f, c)
```

**Result:** Because I am using a one vs. rest approach to my SVM I anticipate that 'cat', 'dog', and 'rat' should be the most important features in the prediction. This is especially true considering that model is 100% accurate on the evaluation dataset. However when I run the code I am seeing the following output:

```
('Label: ', 0)

(u'cat', 1.0)
(u'where', 0.0)
(u'what', 0.0)
    #condensed for space
(u'am', 0.0)
(u'about', 0.0)
(u'dog', -1.0)

('Label: ', 1)

(u'there', 1.0)
(u'dog', 0.0)
(u'about', 0.0)
     #condensed for space
(u'where', 0.0)
(u'cat', 0.0)
(u'is', -1.0)

('Label: ', 2)
(u'do', 1.0)
(u'is', 0.0)
(u'cat', 0.0)
     #condensed for space
(u'dog', 0.0)
(u'there', 0.0)
(u'sat', -1.0)
```

As can be observed, the first class correctly identifies 'cat' as being very important but only considers 'dog' to be uninformative. For the other two labels I am receiving words I would consider uninformative as the most important and least important words.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:** So I have discovered this is in part due to a bug, namely that I was not deep-copying the Feature name list and was manipulating it each time I modified the 'order' for each new label. This explains why the first label made some sense. When I correct this bug I am getting the following output:

```
('Label: ', 0)

(u'cat', 1.0)
(u'where', 0.0)
...
(u'about', 0.0)
(u'dog', -1.0)

('Label: ', 1)

(u'cat', 1.0)
(u'where', 0.0)
...
(u'about', 0.0)
(u'rat', -1.0)

('Label: ', 2)

(u'dog', 1.0)
(u'where', 0.0)
...
(u'about', 0.0)
(u'rat', -1.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem some time ago and thought I would present the answer for those who are looking.

In short, the Sklearn SVM does not perform in a typical one-vs-rest implementation. Instead it uses a wrapper to develop a decision function that combines the decision functions of several one-vs-other classifiers to perform its classification. This approach has changed between implementations and I encourage you to refer to your installation of Sklearn to find out how yours is being performed.